# Switching from multilang to default lang in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

We are using a multilanguage website like

> www.example.com/en/ www.example.com/es/

we have roout config like this

```
$route['switch-language/language/(:any)'] = 'switch_language/language/$1';

$route['en/page/(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1';
$route['fr/page/(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1';
$route['es/page/(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1';
$route['pt/page/(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1';
```

We have a posiblity of turning off language switcher. When we turned off on url we have still www.example.com/en/ format.

Is there a way not showing language tag on the url when multilang switcher is turned off?

Language switcher controlles is like this

```
class Switch_language extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct ();
    }
    function language($language = "") {
        $this->load->model('template_model', '', TRUE);

        $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "english";
        $this->session->set_userdata ( 'site_lang', $language );

        $language_iso = $this->template_model->get_language_iso2_from_language_key($language);
        $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang_iso', strtolower($language_iso));

        //redirect ( base_url () );
        if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){
            //redirect($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
            redirect ( base_url ().strtolower($language_iso) );
        }
        else{
            redirect ( base_url () );
        }
    }
    function language_code() {
        if ($this->input->post ( 'language_save' )) {
            $this->load->model('template_model', '', TRUE);
            $language = $this->input->post ( 'language_key' );

            $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "english";
            $this->session->set_userdata ( 'site_lang', $language );

            $language_iso = $this->template_model->get_language_iso2_from_language_key($language);
            $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang_iso', strtolower($language_iso));

            //redirect ( base_url () );
            if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){
                //redirect($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                redirect ( base_url ().strtolower($language_iso) );
            }
            else{
                redirect ( base_url () );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i remove lang tags from route manually is ok. But need something automatic.

When turned off route would be

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1';
```

need some logic to solve this issue.

Comment: You can leave both routes in your config file

Then do a check if the lang switcher is on/off. 

If it is on and a user tries to access the url that doesn't have the en/es/fr etc. in the url you could redirect them to the appropriate lang url?

Comment: It seems we need to edit language swtch controller. I have added lang switch controlles above.

Comment: May I ask why you decided to go with the lang indicator in the url? Using CI's lang library you can store the language key (en, es etc) in a session variable. The library will automatically load the correct lang from the application/language folder into your site. https://www.tikkibox.com Is an example of a multilingual site I built using CodeIgniter. Perhaps you might consider removing the Lang section from the url?

Comment: how we will solve the seo issue than. Under same url having two different language pages